# Config block returns not found, in hyperledger fabric

Tags: configuration, hyperledger-fabric

Trying to fetch config block to create a config update.
I'm using the test network in fabric samples with default settings (no CA)
even after starting the network I cannot fetch any blocks. not latest or oldest either

This is the output I'm getting

peer channel fetch config

2022-02-08 11:09:47.306 +03 [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2022-02-08 11:09:47.309 +03 [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Expect block, but got status: &{NOT_FOUND}
Error: can't read the block: &{NOT_FOUND}

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the channel, for example:

```
peer channel fetch config -c mychannel
```

That works for me with the default test network channel, and I get the same error you saw without the `-c` option.

It's also worth having a look at the test network scripts since they are meant to be a sample themselves. In this case [configUpdate.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/test-network/scripts/configUpdate.sh) does a config update.